# Audio signal likely spectral distribution (What op-amp slew rate for audio - in practice?)

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, slew-rate

If I'm processing an audio signal (assumed 20 Hz - 20 kHz) in an op-amp circuit and I need to select the slew rate, the simple and obvious, yet conservative answer is \$SR \geq 2\pi f V_{\text{peak}}\$, where \$f = 20 kHz\$.

But a real-life audio signal is not going to be a full-scale 20 kHz tone, and the op-amp is likely overspecified.

Even if we hit it with a [band-limited version of a] 4 kHz square wave (ouch), the 20 kHz component (5th harmonic) has an amplitude of just \$\frac{4}{5\pi}V_{\text{peak}}\$.

Is there an accepted practice for estimating the likely amplitude of the highest frequency components, assuming the input signal is not already so badly distorted that we don't care about the op-amp's performance anyway?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that statistical audio analysis is a good idea? Cymbal crashes contain an awful lot of energy at high frequencies, for example. They might not be common (some percentage of program material, maybe fractional percent of all audio broadcast even?), but the result will be very obviously bad when it does clip.

Comment: At ±15 V, the conservative formula gives 1.9 V/µs. The crappy RC4558 has 1.7 V/µs; the cheap NE5532, 9 V/µs. What do you actually save by using a lower-SR op-amp?

Comment: @CL. This will not be a simple amplifier circuit; there will be some nonlinearity to it. I'm calculating ≥13 V/µs conservatively.

Comment: @CL. Also: This will be a battery-operated circuit. Lower SR op-amps generally use less power.  Higher SR op-amps often have more noise as well.